# Git - How to revert entire directory to specific commit (removing any added files)

Tags: git

I want revert a directory in git - reverting all files inside, as well as removing any files added since that commit.  Doing a checkout only seems to satisfy my first requirement, but doesn't delete any files.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Files not in existence at the time of the commit won't be present if it's checked out, assuming all subsequent changes were also committed.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I figured out the simplest solution.

```
git rm /path/to/dir
git checkout <rev> /path/to/dir
git commit -m "reverting directory"
```

Then delete any untracked files.

```
git rm
```

> > Remove files from the working tree and from the index https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm

```
git checkout
```

> > Updates files in the working tree to match the version in the index or the specified tree. https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

```
git commit
```

> > Record changes to the repository https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-commit

Comment: Nice solution! For directories with sub-directories it's necessary to `git rm -rf /path/to/dir`

Comment: What's `<rev>`?

Comment: @Jarad The revision id, the commit SHA-1 hash e.g. 

commit `cd1ad88a785c8bc05b5e9704b26b860c44218db5` <----- this

Answer (score 9):

**remove only the folder and its content on git**

```
git rm -r --cached myFolder
```

remove folder on git and locally

```
git rm -r myFolder
```

then commit and push again

**To Revert to a previous commit**

```
#reset to previous commit, replace with your commit hash code, you can find it from your commit history 
git reset {commit hash} 

#moves pointer back to previous head branch
git reset --soft HEAD@{1}

git commit -m "Reverted commit to blah"

#update your working copy
git reset --hard
```

**Reverting to part of a commit**
In that case you need to revert to a particular commit and add patch

```
#reset to previous commit, but don't commit the changes
$ git revert --no-commit {last commit hash}   

# unstage the changes
$ git reset HEAD .             

# add/remove stuff here
$ git add file
$ git rm -r myfolder/somefiles          

# commit the changes  
$ git commit -m "fixed something"

# check the files
$ git status

#discard unwanted changes
$ git reset --hard
```

Comment: I'm not looking to delete a folder.  Just revert its contents to a specific point in time.

Comment: But I don't want to reset the entire codebase to a commit.

Comment: then you need to revert and unstage the changes, see updated answer

Answer (score 5):

The top answer is good but I would like to simplify it.

```
git rm -r /path/to/dir
git checkout <rev> /path/to/dir       <-- the <rev> is the git commit id
git commit -m "reverting directory"
```

Everything is exactly the same except the checkout command in my case was:

`git checkout 70157c4f57aa21307cd96f146f8e98b808e1aada ./WebRoot`

I am within a directory called Memento on the command line and I use a dot to denote that the new directory which the git commit info will go into will be in the Memento folder.

I was checking out whatever was in that commit to that folder.

Comment: I am having this error message: _error: pathspec '/path/to/dir' did not match any file(s) known to git_

Answer (score 1):

To restore  so that it matches what it looked like at

First nuke the directory from the staging area

```
git rm --cached -r <directory>
```

Now read in the treeish for just that directory

```
git read-tree <old SHA>^{tree}:<directory> --prefix=<directory>
```

Then commit

```
git commit -m "reverting <directory>"
```

Then just throw out working directory changes that are leftover.

Comment: I'm confused about this: `git read-tree <old SHA>^{tree}:<directory> --prefix=<directory>`  What does this command do?  I get "Not a valid object name".

Comment: did you replace <old_sha>, and the two <directory> entries with the SHA and the directory paths you needed?  It's a low level command that loads up arbitrary directory contents specified by SHA and path

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this in one step using

```
git checkout --no-overlay <ref> -- dir/to/revert
```

`--no-overlay` https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt---no-overlay will remove files not at ref