# How to restore a backup created by .NET upgrade assistant

Tags: c#, .net, upgrade, .net-6.0, .net-framework-version

So I tried upgrading a WPF solution with two projects ( production and unit-tests) that was in .NET Framework 4.7.2.

I made sure to install try convert initially and tested the upgrade tool with a smaller solution and everything worked properly.
But upon use, I encountered some errors and decided that I would rather roll back and start afresh. I explicitly made sure that it made a backup before doing the upgrade. But now I have no idea how to restore the stored local backup .

With what I have searched, there is no documentation at all on the matter. Is the answer so trivial and I'm just missing it? Help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and found no documentation, either online or from the command line in the update-assistant utility itself, that mentioned restoring the backup.

If the backup succeeded you could remove the '.backup' from the backup artifact and delete the upgrade, however I found that in my case the upgrade-assistant utility didn't save the old code accurately, so this didn't work for me.

If your code was in a Git repository you could get it back following the instrucations here:

[Git - How to revert entire directory to specific commit (removing any added files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26048582/git-how-to-revert-entire-directory-to-specific-commit-removing-any-added-file)